# dynamic range based on property giving error

Tags: mule, dataweave

In DataWeave 1.0 I have a requirement to set the "Address" value to a text truncated based on the property "address.length". For example if address.length is > 25 then customer.addressLine1 needs to be truncated to the first 25 chars, otherwise set Address with value in "customer.addressLine1" as it is.

### Code:

```
property file --> address.length=25

(ns2#Address: customer.addressLine1[0.."${address.length}" as :number-1] when ((((sizeOf (customer.addressLine1)) > ("${address.length}" as :number)))) otherwise customer.addressLine1)
```

### Exception:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing: 
                        (ns2#Address: customer.addressLine1[0.."25" as :number-1] when ((((sizeOf (customer.addressLine1)) > ("25" as :number)))) otherwise customer.addressLine1
                                                                      ^
Type mismatch for 'Descendants Selector ..' operator
     found :number
  required :array.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(ns2#Address: customer.addressLine1[0 to "${address.length}" as :number - 1] when (sizeOf (customer.addressLine1)) > ("${address.length}" as :number) otherwise customer.addressLine1)
```

Try with the code above. The range selector is incorrect. It should be `[0 to "${address.length}" as :number - 1]`

The error says that you are using the descendant selector. The range selector should be used.

Comment: Adding to the answer that you should be using the p() function to access properties. Example: `[0 to p("address.length") as :number - 1]`. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/dataweave-reference-documentation#accessing-properties.
Using the `${}` notation inside DataWeave scripts doesn't seem to be documented usage.